# I want to compare to variables and subtract the smallest from the biggest

Tags: java, variables, int, compare

Sorry, guys but I'm really new to this.

I have two variables: totalMonthsA and totalMonthsB each representing an int value. Either value can be bigger or smaller than the other. How do I compare them to find the smaller variable to subtract from the larger one?

Comment: `if (totalMonthsA < totalMonthsB) { ... }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int result = Math.abs(totalMonthsA - totalMonthsB);
```

This computes the absolute value of the difference, which is the same as subtracting the smaller value from the larger.

Figuring out why this is the case is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: While this is true and is a valid answer, it makes me think OP's studying and learning how to do this kind of things by him/herself.

Comment: `Figuring out why this is the case is left as an exercise for the reader :)`  If you tried to find the analog for that statement to the "give a man a fish" saying, it would be like saying `I gave him a fish, but how I got that fish is up for him to figure out`

Comment: @SamIam: Not really. One is a simple case of applying trivial logic, whereas the other requires pure guesswork. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int a=5;
    int b =7;
    int result = a>b?a-b:b-a;
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = totalMonthsA > totalMonthsB ?  
             totalMonthsA - totalMonthsB : totalMonthsB - totalMonthsA
```

this uses the ternary (or the ?: ) operator.

`cond ? a : b` essentially means:  if `cond` then `a` else `b`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class, there are [min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) and [max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) methods there that will help simplify the math.